# Please specify "higher minimum deployment target" dependency

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I installed Flutter 3.16.0 SDK and started installing necessary packages like `connectivity_plus` after configuring it when i tried to run the app on iPhone i got this issue:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "connectivity_plus":
  In Podfile:
    connectivity_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `connectivity_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying couple of things like it did not worked.

- `flutter clean`
- `rm -rf Podfile.lock`
- `rm -rf Pods`
- `pod install --repo-update`
- Updating `Podfile` and setting `platform :ios, '8.0'` or 9.0 or 10.0 or 11.0

I started to worry but then I read the error carefully and started to understand it word by word and i got it that the package that is giving me error have it's minimum platform version which does not match with my platform version in `Podfile` and at this point I don't know what's the package minimum platform version and then I got hint from this part of the error

```
Specs satisfying the `connectivity_plus (from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

So went ahead and opened the `ios/.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios/connectivity_plus.podspec` file and saw it has this `s.platform = :ios, '12.0'` defined in it so i got my answer that this is the minimum platform version i should be using in my `Podfile`.

**TLDR**
Check your `Podfile` and look for this line `platform :ios,` and whatever comes after is the minimum version in my case I tried 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 and 11.0 but it still did not solved my issue so i opened the package `podspec` file which should be located at `ios/.symlinks/plugins/package_name/ios/package_name.podspec` and from there check what's the minimum version and use the same minimum version in your `Podfile`

That's it happy ending